# Single page applications, server-side sessions and page loads

Tags: session, single-page-application

In an SPA with server side sessions, when the user initially loads or refreshes a page, how do you handle authentication state, e.g. rendering whether the user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

Not-Loged-IN:if the user is not loged-in and visits a page a session will already be cretead and it will check for cookie with some session-id and since you were not loged in you donnt have a session-id in any JWT cookie way

if the user was loged in the two cookies hold the values similiar  to like cookie-1:hodling header.payload (secure,30 minute expiry) and cookie:2 holding SIGNATURE (secure,HTTPOnly)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm afraid I do not understand it completely. You say, you always create a session for every user of the page no matter if logged in, or not. Then you have two cookies for logged in users, which container a signature? What kind of signature?

Comment: okk,please have a look at this very good document by Peter Locke : https://medium.com/lightrail/getting-token-authentication-right-in-a-stateless-single-page-application-57d0c6474e3  and then have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFPGOvDrTOk , hope this might help you